NGINX, NodeJS (Docker) problem on Synology
I have a docker-compose file that

Starts Postgres DB
Builds and starts NestJS (NodeJS) backend on localhost:3000
Builds and starts a Angular app on localhost:4200 inside of a NGINX container

I've followed these steps and have successfully managed to connect to my frontend with a nice DNS running on my Synology NAS, but for the backend calls it always gives me CORS error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/my-endpoint. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)

How can I configure the service to run inside of the same network without giving me CORS errors?

Note: When I run the docker-compose command locally it works, just not when I run it on my NAS it won't let me call localhost:3000 from my DNS.

Here is my nginx.conf
events {}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        root /frontend/dist/browser;
        index index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        
        # add locations for JS and CSS
        location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
            expires 1y;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
        }
    }
}

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: ./
      cache_from:
        - frontend
      dockerfile: ./apps/projects/frontend/Dockerfile
    image: frontend
    ports:
      - 4200:80
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    restart: on-failure
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: foo
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: bar
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 1234:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    container_name: backend
    build:
      context: ./
      cache_from:
        - backend
      dockerfile: ./apps/projects/backend/Dockerfile
    image: backend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    restart: on-failure
    
volumes:
  pgdata: {}


I ended up adding the following to my docker-compose.yml so that the DB, BE and FE were running on the same network.
networks:
  my-app-network:

services:
  frontend:
    ...
    networks:
      - my-app-network
  database:
    ...
    networks:
      - my-app-network
  backend:
    ...
    networks:
      - my-app-network

